# I want to retrieve multiple logs from a server with minimum lines of code

Tags: python, file, get, paramiko

I would like to retrieve multiple log files from an Ubuntu server (using Python 2.7 on win 7 machine) without having to write verbose, repetitive code. I'm sure I can use a loop to accomplish this, but I can't come up with any valid solutions (neophyte programmer). I need the direction of someone more seasoned than I. In advanced, I appreciate the help. Below is the code I'm using in my script to log into a server and retrieve one file. Below is a sample path of files I would like to retrieve at the same time:

/var/log/apache/a.log
/var/log/apache/e.log
/var/opt/smart/log/me.log
/var/opt/smart/log/se.log

I have several more paths, but I imagine you get the idea. Below is the code used to log into the server:

```
def do_siteserver(self, line):
   import paramiko



   paramiko.util.log_to_file('c:\Python27\paramiko-wininst.log')

   host = '10.5.48.65'
   port = 22
   transport = paramiko.Transport((host,port))


   while True:
        try:
           print '\n'
           passW = raw_input("Enter the SiteServer weekly password: ") 
           password = passW
           username = 'gilbert'
           print '\n'
           print 'Establishing SFTP connection to: ', host + ':' + str(port), '...'
           transport.connect(username = username, password = password)
           sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
           print 'Authorization Successful!!!'

           filepath = '/var/log/apache2/error.log'
           localpath = 'C:\\remote\\NewFile.log'
           sftp.get(filepath, localpath)
           sftp.close()
           transport.close()
           break


        except:
           print '\n'
           print "Authorization Failed!!!"
           break
```

Comment: You could just use `scp` and not program at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of

```
filepath = '/var/log/apache2/error.log'
localpath = 'C:\\remote\\NewFile.log'
sftp.get(filepath, localpath)
```

I propose this :

```
log_names = {
    "/var/log/apache2/error.log" : 'C:\\remote\\NewFile.log',
    "/var/log/apache/a.log" : 'C:\\remote\\NewFile_a.log',
} # add here all the log files you want to retrieve
for log_file, local_name in log_names.iteritems():
    sftp.get(log_file, local_name)
```

Comment: Julien - ... worked like a charm. I definitely learned something! Thanks!

Comment: @user706808 It wasn't clear that you wanted a different logfile to be recorded for each file retrieved

Answer (score 1):

That ?? :

```
def do_siteserver(self, line):
   import paramiko

   host = '10.5.48.65'
   port = 22
   username = 'gilbert'
   password = raw_input("\nEnter the SiteServer weekly password: ") 

   localpath = 'C:\\remote\\NewFile.log'
   paramiko.util.log_to_file('c:\Python27\paramiko-wininst.log')

   with open(localpath,'w') as lf:

       for filepath in ('/var/log/apache/a.log',
                        '/var/log/apache/e.log',
                        '/var/opt/smart/log/me.log'
                        '/var/opt/smart/log/se.log'):
           try:
               print '\nEstablishing SFTP connection to: {}: {}...'.format(host,port)
               transport = paramiko.Transport((host,port))
               transport.connect(username = username, password = password)
               sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
               print 'Authorization Successful!!!'

               lf.write("Content of server's file :   "+filepath+'\n\n')
               sftp.get(filepath, localpath)
               # or sftp.get(filepath, lf) ? 
               sftp.close()
               transport.close()
               lf.write("\n\n\n")

            except:
               print "\nAuthorization Failed!!!"
               break
```

I understood that you want to record the got contents in only one file of path 'C:\remote\NewFile.log'

I don't know if mixing instruction `sftp.get(filepath, localpath)` and instruction  `lf.write()` is authorized.

.

### EDIT

Now I have understood the aim I can propose a more correct code:

```
def do_siteserver(self, line):
   import paramiko

   host = '10.5.48.65'
   port = 22
   username = 'gilbert'
   password = raw_input("\nEnter the SiteServer weekly password: ") 

   localpath = 'C:\\remote\\NewFile'
   paramiko.util.log_to_file('c:\Python27\paramiko-wininst.log')

   for filepath in ('/var/log/apache/a.log',
                    '/var/log/apache/e.log',
                    '/var/opt/smart/log/me.log'
                    '/var/opt/smart/log/se.log'):
       try:
           print '\nEstablishing SFTP connection to: {}: {}...'.format(host,port)
           transport = paramiko.Transport((host,port))
           transport.connect(username = username, password = password)
           sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
           print 'Authorization Successful!!!'

           sftp.get(filepath, localpath + filepath.replace('/','_'))
           sftp.close()
           transport.close()

        except:
           print "\nAuthorization Failed!!!"
           break
```

BY the way, there is no need of **break** in the **try** portion

Comment: I would not have thought of the optimization that you implemented ... I have a long way to go. Thanks!

Comment: @user706808 Well, I would like to know if it works, in fact. Does the algorithm correspond to what you want to obtain ? Does it work ?, that is to say is it possible to alternate executions of ``sftp.get(filepath, localpath)`` or ``sftp.get(filepath, lf)`` with ``lf.write("Content of server's file :   "+filepath+'\n\n')`` ?

Comment: It logged in successfully (the 'edit' code), but never retrieved the logs. I've decided to scratch retrieving logs altogether, because what I plan to do with them anyway is just to execute a string search on them, and I imagine I can do that just as easy on the server.